# Primer Jekyll theme: How to disable automatic heading link?

Tags: jekyll

Jekyll automatically adds an id attribute to headings and a link to that URL fragment that appears when you mouse over the heading.

I want to disable this for a specific heading which is inside an item detail card which always appears at the top of any page, and the link looks out of place in this context.

Is there a simple way to e.g. mark a specific heading to be excluded, or could the link be removed with some JavaScript? Or is there another HTML tag that I should be using for this type of heading?

The heading is in an HTML layout and I'm using the Primer theme.

Example snippet:

```html
<h2>{{ component.name }}</h2>
```

Result (heading in orange):

[image: rendered HTML showing the undesired anchor element next to the heading]

This card will probably be floated to the left or right of the main page content, wiki style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Primer theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer) includes AnchorJS in line 26 of the default layout as you can see in the [GitHub source](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/6e9de10cb7479acd0a9ce3e69a6951c34c855365/_layouts/default.html#L26).

AnchorJS seems great and pretty flexible. From https://www.bryanbraun.com/anchorjs:

> AnchorJS lets you drop deep anchor links (like these) onto any
> webpage, and be on your way.
>
> You don't need to set up IDs or worry about URLs. AnchorJS will
> respect your IDs if you have them, and generate them if you don't.
>
> It uses an attractive link icon by default, but you can customize the
> display via options and CSS styling.

The page also explains different ways [how to remove anchors](https://www.bryanbraun.com/anchorjs/#removing-anchors), here's the one you most probably need to target only specific headings:

```
/**
 * Example 2
 * Add anchors to all h2s, except for those with a class of "no-anchor".
 */
anchors.add('h2:not(.no-anchor)');
```

In your case, you could add a CSS class on your special h2 and it will not show an anchor anymore if you target the class with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Christian's answer gets to the heart of the issue, but because one cannot change the way Primer adds the links without replacing the whole default.html file, it may be easier to hide the link with CSS.

```css
/* also add class="no-anchor" to heading tags in HTML */
.no-anchor .anchorjs-link {
    display: none;
}
```

However, this leaves the ID intact so someone determined enough could still link to that heading.

Comment: Great that you have found a pragmatic solution